# How do I get the value of an XML child node?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-4.5

I have a file containing thousands of waypoints in the following form:

```
<wpt lat="45.1058149" lon="-88.316769">
   <ele>256</ele>
   <type>Tower</type>
   <extensions>
      <label xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/gpx_overlay/0/3">
         <label_text>Bagley Lookout Tower</label_text>
      </label>
   </extensions>
</wpt>
```

I have no problem getting the latitude, longitude, elevation, and type from each entry. I can't however figure out how to get the label_text value.

Here is the code that works for getting the elevation, trimmed down to the minimum code.

```
var waypoints = from waypoint in gpxDoc.Descendants(gpx + "wpt")
  select new
  {
     Elevation = waypoint.Element(gpx + "ele") != null ? waypoint.Element(gpx + "ele").Value : null,
     Type = waypoint.Element(gpx + "type") != null ? waypoint.Element(gpx + "type").Value : null,
  };
```

How do I get the value of label_text?

Thanks!

Update: Here's my latest attempt to get this working. Unfortunately, I'm still not making any progress to getting the real value I'm seeking. I'm getting `LabelText = null`.

```
LabelText = waypoint.Element(gpx + "extensions").Element(gpx + "label") != null ? waypoint.Element(gpx + "extensions").Element(gpx + "label").Element(gpx + "label_text").Value : null,
```

Comment: You can reduce your ternary statements to `Type = (string)waypoint.Element(gpx + "type")`.  For `<label_type>`, you'll have to work your way down the document tree.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Label = (string)waypoint.Element(gpx + "extensions").Element(topo + "label")
    .Element(topo + "label_text")
```

where

```
XNamespace topo = "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/gpx_overlay/0/3";
```

Comment: In my experience, if "label" or "label_text" are null, you'll get an exception.  The cast to `string` only applies to the first element, not the children.

Comment: Instead of `topo + "label"` you can write `"{http://www.topografix.com/GPX/gpx_overlay/0/3}label"`. Not that it's better, it's just another possibility.